# Programatically create new CSS rules in a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, dom

For creating new CSS rules in a stylesheet, as of now, I only know `.insertRule()` (excluding the non-standard ways).

Are there any other ways of creating more CSS rules? Something, for example:
**Warning: this is not standard, it is just an example to display the intent**

```
var rule = new CSSStyleRule();
rule.selectorText = '.selector';
rule.style.display = 'block';
rule.style.color = 'red';
ruleSet.append(rule);
```

Anything like or somewhat like the above works as an answer. Instead of `new`, it may be `document.createCssRule()` or `stylesheet.createCssRule()`...
I just this it would be useful for a piece of software I'm developing which left me if there's a programatically way of modifying values in such interface where to add new stuff is not restricted to a parsed string.

Do not worry about IE9 and below when answering, please.

**Note:** (to unclose) This is not about how to find and modify current CSS rules, this is about making new ones without using the text parser which is what `.insertRule()` is without building a complete CSS string like `.insertRule()` requires.

Comment: do you know less ? http://lesscss.org/

Comment: i think there's also a .js less parser

Comment: The code you posted can work as it is, if you create the associated classes: http://jsfiddle.net/8s6otsc3/

Comment: @Baci Yes... What about it?

Comment: @xdhmoore the .js less parser is the original. All the others are adaptations to their corresponding programming languages.

Comment: @blex Although the code is quite nice and it seems to work quite well, actually, it is against the good practices of not overloading browsers' default objects :S. I'd rather not... Regardless of that, the code is interesting.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule Modify example 2 to suit your needs.

Comment: @Shmiddty not really helpful, though. It is still using `insertRule()` or string concatenation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an empty rule, get it, and modify it:

```js
function appendRule(sheet) {
  var len = sheet.cssRules.length;
  sheet.insertRule('*{}', len);
  return sheet.cssRules[len];
}
var rule = appendRule(document.styleSheets[0]);
rule.selectorText = '.selector';
rule.style.display = 'block';
rule.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<span class="selector">I should become red.</span>
<span>I should be at the next line and not become red.</span>
```

However, modifying `selectorText` does not seem to work on Firefox.

Comment: According to the duplicate question's answer, you should use `var cssRuleCode = document.all ? 'rules' : 'cssRules';` to make it work in Firefox too.

Comment: @blex I think that is for ancient IE. Firefox supports `cssRules`, but the `selectorText` setter does not seem to work.

Comment: This would be the accepted answer if it wasn't for the unimplemented code on firefox's side ...

Comment: Firefox has finally implemented the API

Answer (score 2):

You could append a new `style` element to your `head` and just append rules to it:

```
function addStyle(newRules){
    if(document.getElementById("jsAddedRules")){
        document.getElementById("jsAddedRules").innerHTML+=newRules;
    }else{
        var style=document.createElement("style");
        style.setAttribure("id","jsAddedRules");
        style.innerHTML=newRules;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
    }
}
```

And then just call your function when you want to add rules:

```
addStyle(
    ".selector{\
        display:block;\
        color:red;\
    }"
);
```

Comment: Yeah... it works... It is not well maintainable, though. If I want to change anything, it can become a mess because I still need to retain all values used or I need to parse CSS.